# What files do I upload in a C# Web API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

** Dumb questions alert **

I created my first Web API project.  I would like to test it on my web host, but I can't figure out what files to upload.  I tried to upload everything from the HelloWorld folder, but I get a 403 "Access is denied" error when I attempt to access the files.

Once I upload the folders/files, how do I access them?  Do I have to navigate to the Root > Views > Home > ... ?

Folder Structure

- HelloWorld

  - HelloWorld
  - _UpgradeReport_Files

    - 1 css, 1 xslt, 4 pngs
  - HelloWorld

    - All of my folders and files
    - This is what I tried to upload
  - packages

    - A lot of ASP and JQuery folders

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I'm struggling to understand your comment.  The first link points to a post stating "Stack Overflow is not customer support".  I have to assume you posted the wrong link since I'm not asking for product-specific support.  I'm asking for someone with MVC experience to tell me what to upload.  The 2nd link is a link to ASP.net's forums.  Are you suggesting that all ASP.net questions should be posted to ASP.net's forums instead of Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two separate problems here: knowing what files to deploy and getting the permissions correct so that you can access them.

In general, the files you will need to deploy are all of your static files (images, CSS, Javascript, HTML), any .cshtml/.aspx/.ascx/.asax files, and Web.config.  However, the easiest (and best) way to know what files to deploy is to use Visual Studio's publishing mechanism.  Go to Build->Publish, and publish to a local directory.  Open that directory, and you'll see all the files you need to deploy.

As far as the second problem, that's more complicated.  The solution depends on the version of IIS, but the basic upshot is that you need to give the correct user access permissions to your file.  Depending on your version of IIS and how it's confusing, it will either be IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, or NETWORK SERVICE.  Try Googling for "file permissions IIS ".

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I will test the publishing process and report back with any follow-up questions.  I'm deploying it to a shared web host, so I won't know the details of the IIS version.